# Magento 2.3 Not Sending any Emails

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I am using Magento 2.3 installed via web hosting Cpanel.

I am testing the emails but nothing was sent to my emails in hotmail or gmail or personal hosting emails

nor sending to spam folder

I tested the email sending from another script (Wordpress) on my hosting and it was working fine I get emails

I have tested using my hosting emails also gmail email it doesn't work
not sending :

- register confirmation link email
- password reset email
- order transaction email
- newsletter emails

these are my configuration on admin panel:

[image]

[image]

BTW, as you see on the page , there is no option for SMTP Configuration (thus I don't have mail server I am using my hosting Email server )

this is my hosting server information:

[image]

I have added `mail()` function at the end of `index.php` file of magento root and it is working

[image]

[image]

How Can I fix this issue?

Regards,

Comment: Most likely CRON jobs aren't configured correctly

Comment: I didn't do anything on it, it is fresh install

Comment: Yeah, most likely you need to set up Cron jobs on the server. Posted as an answer below

Comment: @AhmadSaleh: Have you resolved this issue? I am facing the same. Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to set up the Magento CronTab.
Instructions listed here [Setting Up Magento CronTab](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html)